# PostgreSql какой тип данных использовать для русских слов?

Tags: postgresql

В PostgreSql нету NVARCHAR как правильно записывать русские слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычные text и varchar. У postgresql нет проблем с поддержкой юникода, чтобы потребовался какой-то явный костыль в виде отдельного типа данных.

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый ответ!